# How can I debug my verilog code for concatenating the MSB to LSB of 2 4bit number?

Tags: verilog, hdl

It complains `Input a<2:0>` and `Input b<2:0>` is never used .The output is just displaying the concatenation of `a[3]` and `b[3]` (`a = 1001`, `b = 1100`).

```
module stone(a,b,rslt);
  input      [3:0] a,b;
  output reg [0:1] rslt;
  integer i;
  always @(a,b)
  begin
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + 1)
      rslt =  {a[i],b[i]};
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: What do you want as output? The single 8-bit value `10011100`; or `11` in the first clock cycle, then `01`, then `00`, and then `10`?

Comment: I see that you don't have a clock signal, so in case you want the second option, you need some sort of clock signal as an input to your module.

Comment: I just need 2 bit for every clock cycle nd ive tried using a clock its not working

Comment: In order to attract more answers that are helpful to you, you should edit your question so it becomes more clear what exactly you want to do and what you have already tried (for example, how you have attempted to use a clock, and how that didn't give you the result you want).

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop you are using is equivalent to the following code:

```
rslt = {a[0], b[0]};
rslt = {a[1], b[1]};
rslt = {a[2], b[2]};
rslt = {a[3], b[3]};
```

This means that in the end only the last statement has an effect and the first three do not.

Comment: I know that's the way it works ,im just asking what is the correct way,thanks.